# $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle (0,1)\rangle$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle (1,2) \rangle$ isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle (0,1)\rangle$$

I can see that $\langle0,1\rangle$ has order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4$, so the quotient has order $\frac{2\cdot 4}{4} = 2$. However, my book's answer says that then this is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Why, exactly? In this case, I could calculate the small table of elements, and see that its behaviour is exactly as $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but there are not so obvious examples, like:

$$(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle (1,2) \rangle$$

which has $4$ elements. In this one, the book says it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ because the element $(1,1) + \langle (1,2)\rangle$ has order $4$. Why? If an element has order equal to the lenght of the group, then it's isomorph to it? Could somebody make it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the only group of order $2$, so once you determine that your group has order $2$, you know it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Similarly, up to isomorphism, there are only $2$ groups of order $4$. One of them is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and the other is the Klein-$4$ group $K_4$. In $\mathbb{Z}_4$ there is an element of order $4$, but there is no such element in $K_4$. So if your group has an element of order $4$ it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$. Otherwise it is isomorphic to $K_4$.

Answer (score 0):

If a group has an element of order equal to the order of the group then the group is called cyclic.This means you can take iterates of that particular element under the group operation to get the entire group.Since in these both cases we have such an element after quotienting thus the result.Why? because any finite cyclic group of order n is isomorphic to $Z_n$. Just send a generator to generator and you can do it.